# Django favourite/compare feature

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, web, django-sessions

Just wondering if Sessions can be used to create a quick compare view of two products on my Django app. I'm listing items for sale and would like a user to be able to 'like' multiple items then have a new view to compare the selected products. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just assign the list products to a session variable.

Then assign the products list to the template, which could look something like that:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    {% for product in products %}
    <th>{{ product.title }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Feature 1</th>
    {% for product in products %}
    <td>{{ product.feature1 }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Feature 2</th>
    {% for product in products %}
    <td>{{ product.feature2 }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks looks good, do you have an example of how to CBV would look?